# Diff the output of two `awk` commands

Tags: shell, io-redirection, awk, diff

I'm trying to compute the difference between the output of two `awk` commands but my simple attempts at it seem to be failing. Here is what I'm trying:

```
diff $(awk '{print $3}' f1.txt | sort -u) $(awk '{print $2}' f2.txt | sort -u)
```

This doesn't work for reasons unknown to me. I was under the assumption that `$()` construct was used to capture the output of another command but my "diff" invocation fails to recognize the two inputs given to it. Is there any way I can make this work.

By the way, I can't use the obvious solution of writing the output of those two commands to separate files given that I'm logged on to a production box with no 'write' privileges.

Comment: try writing output of both awk functions into different files and compare them using diff command

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't acceptable since I'm logged on to a production box with no write access.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`diff` expects the names of two files, so you should put the two output on two files, then compare them:

```
awk '{print $3}' f1.txt | sort -u > out1
awk '{print $2}' f2.txt | sort -u > out2
diff out1 out2
```

or, using `ksh93`, `bash` or `zsh`, you can use process substitution:

```
diff <(awk '{print $3}' f1.txt | sort -u) <(awk '{print $2}' f2.txt | sort -u)
```

Comment: Wow, the second solution works like a charm (unfortunately can't use first since I can't create a file on that box). BTW, can you throw some pointers/links on what kind of black magic this `<()` construct is and what is it called?

Comment: @sasuke: See this other answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22645/what-does-a-redirection-mean/22646#22646

Comment: @sasuke you don't need to put outX in the same dir, you could put them in ~/ or /tmp/. You should have some place on the machine you could create tmp files even on a "production box".

Comment: @Johan: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, the "production" box is a bit borked when it comes to configuration so all developers have strictly read only rights (yes, even home directories, sad but true).

Comment: @sasuke `/tmp` should still be writable though, or the system is truly borked.