# Shell redirection: <<<'foo' vs <(echo 'foo')

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I've seen both `<<<'foo'` and `<(echo 'foo')` suggested as alternatives to echoing to pipes (`echo foo | cat`).

When I use both of these constructs with cat I get:

```
$ cat <<<'foo'
foo
$ cat <(echo 'foo')
foo
```

So far, so expected.

A difference becomes apparent however when you use them on the shell directly:

```
$ <<<'foo'
foo
$ <(echo 'foo')
zsh: permission denied: /dev/fd/12
```

I am using zsh, and bash seems to treat the `<<<` case differently, printing nothing at all, but is the same as zsh in the `<()` case.

But what actually triggered my question was a diff:

```
$ diff <<<"/mypath" <(pwd)
diff: missing operand after `/dev/fd/63'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
```

It's clear there's a fundamental difference between these two types of shell redirection. Can anyone explain the difference?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `<()` is a sub-shell being replaced with a string, and is not being attached to stdin of the process, whereas `<<<` does attach to stdin like `<` does, but I'm not 100% on this, so an authoritative answer that explains the fundamentals would be beneficial to many I think!

Comment: `<()` is "process substitution", `<<<` is a herestring. Look up the docs for those and you will see they're quite unrelated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators) and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22645/what-does-a-redirection-mean/22646

Comment: Agree that the linked wiki covers this, but I don't agree that it's a duplicate question. Yes, I could find the answer in documentation or the linked wiki answer, but surely the point of Q&A sites such as this is to ask and answer more specific questions about a topic? If this question is a duplicate of that wiki answer, then so is every question tagged io-redirection. Practically every question on the site could be tagged as a dupe of a man page.

Comment: Wells you'll have fun going through the dupes of that question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/159513?lq=1

Comment: As you are a highly active user I can understand your frustration, but a lot of those dupes have a fair few up-votes, which shows they have value to readers

Comment: You may be interested in https://askubuntu.com/a/678919/295286 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<<< text` is a redirection, if affects the file descriptors of a command (here 0, but `4<<< text` would affect the fd 4 instead).

While `<(...)` is an expansion/substitution, not a redirection. That expands to a file name. That affects the arguments passed to a command if inserted there.

```
cat <(echo test)
```

Runs `cat` with a file like `/dev/fd/12` as argument. And as it happened also with its fd 12 being open on the reading end of a pipe. `cat` will not read from its fd 12, but when it opens the `/dev/fd/12` file, it will get a new fd (maybe 3) that points to the same pipe as fd 12.

Meanwhile `echo test` is run in background with its fd 1 connected to the writing end of that same pipe, so `echo` and `cat` will end up being connected via that pipe (though the establishment of that communication channel is much more convoluted than with `echo text | cat`).

```
cat <<< text
```

Runs cat without argument and with its fd 0 open for reading on a deleted temporary file that contains `test\n`.

zsh interprets

```
<<< test
```

as

```
$NULLCMD <<< test
```

(`$NULLCMD` being typically `cat`) as happens any time you run something with only redirections (except when there's only one `<` redirection, in which case `$READNULLCMD` (typically a pager) is used instead)).

In:

```
<(echo text)
```

There's no redirection, just one process substitution that expands to one /dev/fd/12 argument. So that's asking the shell to execute that file.

In zsh, there's no real benefit of using:

```
cat <(echo test)
cat < <(echo test)
```

over

```
echo test | cat
```

You see this construct in other shells like bash in things like:

```
IFS= read -r var < <(echo text)
```

but that's because in those shells, `echo text | IFS= read -r var` would not work because `read` is run in a child process. That's not the case in `zsh`.

Process substitution is useful for commands that only accept input via a file name as argument (and not via stdin) of when you need to pass more than one input to a command (there's only one stdin) like in `diff <(cmd1) <(cmd2)`.

One difference in `zsh` between `cmd1 | cmd2` and `cmd2 < <(cmd1)` is that in the latter, `zsh` doesn't wait for `cmd1`. While it does wait for both `cmd1` and `cmd2` in `cmd1 | cmd2` (if only so as to make both exit statues available in `$pipestatus`. Compare `sleep 1 | uname` with `uname < <(sleep 1)`.

`cmd <<< foo` can be useful when `cmd` needs to be able to seek into it's input (because in `zsh`, here-strings like here-documents are implemented with temporary files instead of pipes).

Comment: This answer is great, but it's missing the explanation for the final `diff <<<"/mypath" <(pwd)`, which is explained by the fact `diff` still wants two file names and you need to pass an extra `-` for it to read from stdin, which is what `<<<"/mypath"` is. (Also, using `diff` and that many redirections for this is way overkill!)

Comment: `zsh` will wait for `cmd1` in `cmd2 < <(cmd1)` if `cmd2` is a built-in, compound command or function. Compare `true < <(sleep 2)` vs `/bin/true < <(sleep 2)`. `bash` will only wait for it if it's a compound command or function, not if it's a built-in. See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/524844/308316).

Comment: This is a great answer thank you; exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: And yes, diff is way overkill, I just wanted a quick way to determine where the typo was in a particularly long path. Most people would probably just compare the strings manually!